# How can I get the issuer hash in nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl, tls1.2, nginx-reverse-proxy

As stated in the title, I want to pass the issuer hash of the client certificate to the service behind the nginx.

By using the openssl from the command line I can get the issuer hash as given,

- `openssl x509 -in B0100002230000023.crt -noout -issuer_hash`
- `Example Output: 529e9f5d`

But I could not get the same value using the nginx. There is an example configuration below, in the `SOME_VAR_TO_GET_HASH` there should be a some kind of variable, or function to get it but I could not find it.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/client-cer/ROOT.crt;
    ssl_verify_client      optional;

    location /default/controller/ {
        if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
           return 403;
        }

        proxy_pass http://app.behind:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Ssl-Issuer-Hash-1 [SOME_VAR_TO_GET_HASH];
   }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.